# data.table object redundancy

Tags: r, data.table

I am trying to get used to data.table notation and would like to clean up this code a bit. I feel as if there is a better and less memory greedy way to handle this problem. I need to calculate some basic metrics on an existing data frame. Can I do it without creating multiple data tables? Also, how do I handle the NaN problem with a 0 in the denom. I would like it to print 0.

```
library("Lahman")
library("ggplot2")
library("data.table")

DT <- na.omit(data.table(PlayerId = Batting$playerID, SB = Batting$SB, 
               CS = Batting$CS, G = Batting$G))

DTa <- (DT[, list(TotalSB = sum(SB), TotalCS = sum(CS), TotalG = sum(G)), 
        by = 'PlayerId'])

DTb <- (DTa[,
        list(PlayerId, TotalSB, TotalCS, TotalG, 
            SBAttempts = TotalSB + TotalCS, 
            SBSuccess = TotalSB / (TotalSB + TotalCS),
            SBPerGame = TotalSB / TotalG)
           ])

print(DTb)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, here's a slightly more compact way.

```
# don't need quotes in `by=...`
DTa <- (DT[, list(TotalSB = sum(SB), TotalCS = sum(CS), TotalG = sum(G)), 
           by = PlayerId])
# use c(...):=list(...) to add multiple columns
DTa[,c("SBAttempts","SBSuccess","SBPerGame"):=
      list(TotalSB + TotalCS,TotalSB / (TotalSB + TotalCS),TotalSB / TotalG)]
# replace NAN with 0
DTa[,names(DTa)[5:7]:=lapply(.SD,function(x)ifelse(is.nan(x),0,x)),.SDcols=5:7]
```

This does create a new data table `DTa`, because this table has fewer rows than the original table. The extra columns `TotalXX` are added, and the NaN's are converted to 0's, by reference (no copying).